# How to grab elements by class or id in HTML Source in C#?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to grab elements from HTML source based on the class or id name, using C# windows forms application. I am putting the source into a string using WebClient and plugging it into the HTMLAgilityPack using HtmlDocument.

However, all the examples I find with the HTMLAgilityPack pack parse through and find items based on tags. I need to find a specific id, of say a link in the html, and retrieve the value inside of the tags. Is this possible and what would be the most efficient way to do this? Everything I am trying to parse out the ids is giving me exceptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this with XPath:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"file.htm");

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"my_control_id\"]");
string value = (node == null) ? "Error, id not found" : node.InnerHtml;
```

Quick explanation of the xpath here:

- `//` means search everywhere in the path, Use `SelectNodes` if it will be matching multiples
- `*` means match any type of node
- `[]` define "Predicates" which are basically checking properties relative to this node
- `[@id=\"my_control_id\"]` means find nodes that have an attribute named "id" with the value "my_control_id"

[Further reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Thank you, should I use this instead of the HTMLAgilityPack? I am definiing the HtmlDocument with HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument. Your code makes sense that it should work but I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception every time when I try to execute it. I can't seem to just use HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); as it says it has no constructor.

Comment: I was using HTMLAgilityPack for that.  Do you have another class called HtmlDocument somewhere?  Maybe try `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()`  Also example edited to check for null node.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! yes the HtmlAgilityPack is the HtmlDocument I have been using. The node is definitely being returned as null no matter which id or class I choose within the html source and I am now getting that error message rather than the exception, so that will be my last bit to figure out.

Comment: Maybe look at `doc.ParseErrors` and see if its throwing up on parsing your page?

Comment: yes there does seem to be something populated there. that would be a separate issue i would imagine. thanks again, very helpful!

Comment: Is it possible to do `[@id=\"*my_control_id\"]` which is gonna match any element with id has suffix "my_control_id"?

Comment: @user You can do `contains`: `//a[contains(@id,'Foo')]`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains  I'm not seeing any "ends-with" type functions